How to interpolate 3d variable like RAINC from netcdf file using wrf-python
Currently ,I am working on netcdf file ,from which i need to extract data using wrf-python and plot in the graph,
while plotting , i got an issue ( i have attached the image, you can refer it).
Before explaining issue, i would like to explain the variable,RAINC which depends on timeindex,longitude and latitude, like RAINC[0,25,90]
but while plotting these,it values differ largely in small longitude and latitude change,which is giving a odd looking image
like:

what i need is ,i want to interpolate this rainc varaible
like
time  longitude latitude
1       1           1         rainc->5
time longitude latitude
1     1           3           rainc->10
irrespective of value at 2 latitude,it should be done by interpolating 5 and 10
ps: i am not mathematician.  i may be wrong about explaining interpolation,but hope you get it

Do you want to interpolate only along one axis? E.g. in your example should your rainc also integrate what neighboring valuas are there for longitude 0 and and longitude 2? Do want this interpolation to be applied to specific values (e.g. above/below a certain threshold)? Is the data already structured as an array? If so, convolution might be a nice tool to achieve want you want.

what i really need is:
suppose you are travelling to some area (lat :20,long:90) :
currently if you move one unit more, its value changes suddenly,
i donot want this , i want linearly change the value like gradually increasing or decreasing

Can you put more information on the netCDF files that you are using? If possible, use ncdump -h your.nc in a terminal because that will show us what the structure of the file is. One possible issue might be that your grid is rotated latitude-longitude, for instance.

i am using netcdf file which is output of WRF model,
for interpolation, i have used the  smooth2d() provided by wrf-python

You can use   smooth2d()function for interpolation  if your data is 2d. But your netcdf file must be supported by wrf-python( which is output of WRF model)
